# List and modal in framework7

Tags: javascript, cordova, html-framework-7

I am trying to fix this problem 2 days and I am a rookie in Javascript
Currently I am Using visual studio + Cordova + Framework 7

```
var pet1 = select_all('pet');

    $$('#pet1').empty();

    $$.each(pet1, function (index, value) {

        $$('#pet1').append('<li>'
            + '<div class="item-link item-content">'
            + '      <div class="item-media">'
            + '          <img style="width:80px;height:60px" src="http://file.nowdb.net/' + value.cover + '">'
            + '      </div>'
            + '      <div class="item-inner">'
            + '          <div class="item-title-row">'
            + '              <div class="item-title">' + value.title + '</div>'
            + '              <div class="item-after">Element label</div>'
            + '          </div>'
            + '          <div class="item-subtitle">' + value.description + '</div>'
            + '          <div class="item-text">Additional description text</div>'
            + '      </div>'
            + '</div>'
            + '</li>');

    });
```

and this work well

after that i found a documentation in Framework 7 that call Modal With Slider
and the code is in here http://framework7.io/docs/modal.html

which call open-slider-modal

I don't know why cant copy the code
[image: gj1515]

But the problem for me is I don't know how to add this code into it 
Please help me , between sorry for my bad English.
thanks everyone

Comment: If I understand, ou want to have 1 slide per 'pet' ?

Comment: @Djiggy No no bro
I have succesfull create a list call pet1 , pet is my collection in database
and right now i hope i can create a modal in this list after i click it
maybe $$(document).on click function?

Comment: I'm not sure what you ask. you do not want your list in the slider modal but just show image in the modal on click ?

Comment: @Djiggy okay .. right now i have a media list view inside my page ,and now i need to create a new function when i Click the element inside , the modal will show up .

Comment: Ok, so simply add an event listener to you `item-link` class and create your modal inside ?

Comment: @Djiggy thanks for your help dude , i finish it in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Okay I finished it myself already , will post the answer here for help the others who facing same problem like me

```
var pet1 = select_all('pet');

$$('#pet1').empty();

$$.each(pet1, function (index, value) {

    $$('#pet1').append('<li>'
        + '<div class="item-link item-content">'
        + '      <div class="item-media">'
        + '          <img style="width:80px;height:60px" src="http://file.nowdb.net/' + value.cover + '">'
        + '      </div>'
        + '      <div class="item-inner">'
        + '          <div class="item-title-row">'
        + '              <div class="item-title">' + value.title + '</div>'
        + '              <div class="item-after">Element label</div>'
        + '          </div>'
        + '          <div class="item-subtitle">' + value.description + '</div>'
        + '          <div class="item-text">Additional description text</div>'
        + '      </div>'
        + '</div>'
        + '</li>');

});
```

just

continue the code below

```js
$$('.open-slider-modal').on('click', function () {
  var modal = myApp.modal({
    title: 'Awesome Photos?',
    text: 'What do you think about my photos?',
    afterText:  '<div class="swiper-container" style="width: auto; margin:5px -15px -15px">'+
                  '<div class="swiper-pagination"></div>'+
                  '<div class="swiper-wrapper">'+
                    '<div class="swiper-slide"><img src="..." height="150" style="display:block"></div>' +
                    '<div class="swiper-slide"><img src="..." height="150" style="display:block"></div>'+
                  '</div>'+
                '</div>',
    buttons: [
      {
        text: 'Bad :('
      },
      {
        text: 'Awesome!',
        bold: true,
        onClick: function () {
          myApp.alert('Thanks! I know you like it!')
        }
      },
    ]
  })
  myApp.swiper($$(modal).find('.swiper-container'), {pagination: '.swiper-pagination'});
});
```

and then

first change the

```
$$('.open-slider-modal').on('click', function () {
```

to

```
$$(document).on('click', '.open-slider-modal', function () {
```

change the class inside your list

```
<div class="item-media open-slider-modal">'
```

you will be done